PowerBI- Change visual output based on single filter
I'm working on a report where I want to change the output of a visual element based on what is selected on the filter rather than the values. I've included images below.
I currently have two slicers on the page. I want to consolidate this into one. I want the First-Time or Transfer slicer to remain. When First Time is selected, the matrix visual should populate with the High School Attended data. When Transfer is selected, it should show Last_College.
Right now, I would have to select Last_College when Transfer is selected and High School Attended when First Time is selected. The Colleges or High School slicer was built using a parameter and I placed the parameter on the matrix visual.
Is there a way to have that parameter controlled by the First-Time or Transfer slicer?



Can you please provide some sample data and an expected output? Can you also explain what you mean by "the parameter was placed on the matrix"?
